# How to remove the ',' when converting Javascript object to .csv file?

Tags: javascript, csv, object

I need to convert javascript some objects like this:

```
{available :null
avg: null
current:116
max:null
min:null
status:"Pending, Charged Off"
balance:-166085.77}
```

using other people's js code and adding a little bit my code for get API, which including two functions the first one is for converting:

```
$scope.convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV = function (args) {
        var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

        data = args.data || null;
        if (data == null || !data.length) {
            return null;
        }

        columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
        lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

        keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

        result = '';
        result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
        result += lineDelimiter;

        data.forEach(function(item) {
            ctr = 0;
            keys.forEach(function(key) {
                if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

                result += item[key];
                ctr++;
            });
            result += lineDelimiter;
        });

        return result;
    }
```

the second one is for downloading :

```
$scope.downloadCSV = function (args) {
        var data, filename, link;
        //my code:
        $http.get(
                 apis[$scope.selectedKeys[0]]
            ).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.data = data;
        })
        var stringData = angular.toJson($scope.data.items);
        $scope.newData = JSON.parse(stringData);
        console.log($scope.newData);
        //my code end
        var csv = $scope.convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
            data: $scope.newData 
        });
        if (csv == null) return;

        // filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';
        filename =  $scope.selectedKeys[0] + '.csv';

        if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
            csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
        }
        data = encodeURI(csv);

        link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', data);
        link.setAttribute('download', filename);
        link.click();
    }
```

It works fine, only one problem is when some columns with the comma like this in object: status:"Pending, Charged Off" will be converted in to another column in csv file. I think I need to do something with this line:

```
columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
```

but do not know how to do? Can any one help? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: I'm not sure whether you need to do it yourself or if you can just use an opensource library, there are quite a few libraries for JSON to CSV conversion [here's just one of the results I found](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-2-csv), most will have some way to help with those issues

Comment: Thank you @PatrickBarr definitely, I will check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An homemade-solution can be use quotation marks.

```
$scope.convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV = function (args) {
        var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

    data = args.data || null;
    if (data == null || !data.length) {
        return null;
    }

    columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
    lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

    keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

    result = '';
    result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
    result += lineDelimiter;

    data.forEach(function(item) {
        ctr = 0;
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
            if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

            result += '"' + item[key].replace('\"', "&quot;") + '"';
            ctr++;
        });
        result += lineDelimiter;
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is that `&quot;` doing there? Are you outputting CSV in HTML?

Comment: Hi Nicolò Boschi, thank you so much! It throws an error: item[key].replace is not a function, but I think it's the right direction.

Comment: Hi Nicolò Boschi, your answer is correct, just some of my data: item[key] has different data type, so inspired by your answer, I add couple line of code, it works: if(typeof(item[key]) === "string" && item[key].includes(",")){
      item[key] = item[key].replace('\"', "&quot;");
    }
    result += '"' + item[key] + '"';

Answer (score 0):

To get `,` in a value surround it with double quotes `"`:

```
foo,"foo,bar",bar
```

Is interpreted in CSV as:

```
[ "foo", "foo,bar", "bar" ]
```

But what if your value also has a double quote in it? ie:

```
foo,"foo",bar",bar
```

Now this is just a mess. You need to *escape* the double quote by adding another double quote:

```
foo,"foo"",bar",bar
```

Gives:

```
[ "foo", "foo\",bar", "bar" ]
```